# Selenium 2 C# Webdriver - Why can't I move from one input to another in IE8?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I've run into a quirky issue with WebDriver and IE8, and I'm curious if anyone else has seen this before. In a nutshell, I have a test that steps over a set of input fields, enters text, and then clicks on a submit button (none of which are in a `<form>`.) It works fantastically in Firefox 3.6, like so:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(domainXpath)).SendKeys("someDomain");
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(emailXpath)).SendKeys("someEmailAddress");
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(passwordXpath)).Sendkeys("somePassword");
```

But when I run this against IE8, Selenium never seems to change fields, even though it appears to be locating them correctly via the specified XPath.

At first, I thought this might be a problem with xpath-ing (I've seen others with related problems), but my SendKeys isn't failing with any "element not found" errors, and other elements I'm clicking on are working fine. In fact, Selenium is able to find the first field in this list and dumps all the text for all three Finds into that field.

So, then I changed the code just slightly, like so:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(domainXpath)).SendKeys("someDomain\t");
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(emailXpath)).SendKeys("someEmailAddress\t");
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(passwordXpath)).Sendkeys("somePassword\t");
```

...and, Voila, the text got entered properly.

It's as if IE is ignoring Selenium's request to move to the next field, in spite of the fact that the field is reporting present.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there some way to avoid having to write special code for IE, just to append tabs to every item of data?

Thanks,
Greg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this problem appears to be a compatibility issue (or coding bug) between IE8 and the app under test. I'm still sorting it out, and will have more details shortly, but for now, the question seems answered.

Sorry for cluttering the stream... [embarrassed]